# Selector tag in android

Tags: android

I am working on the home screen application, where I am trying to do some changes to existing one. I downloaded code from Mydroid folder. And when analyzing that I found that they used selector tag in XML file, but I couldn't understand where exactly they used that to achieve its functionality.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_allshow" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_allhide" />
</selector>
```

It is present in res/drawable folder.

Comment: Are you asking where the selector is used? As in where you can find the code: android:drawable="@drawable/my_selector"? Or are you asking how selectors work?

Comment: Thanku for replying . I mean to ask how selector works in code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A selector tag basically looks for the state of the UI at the time and displays the appropriate image.

This particular drawable is for a check box, when the checkbox is in the state

```
 android:state_checked="false"
```

(i.e. when the checkbox is not checked)

it uses this image:

```
 @drawable/ic_launcher_allshow
```

Therefore , checked:

```
 android:state_checked="true"
```

uses

```
 @drawable/ic_launcher_allhide
```

See here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

&

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html